# Handling kivy event inside python code

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I have problem with running a piece of code for on_press event here is my code:

## MAIN.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.4



import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.7')



from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class helloworldApp(App):
    def action(self):
        print('Hi')




app=helloworldApp()
app.run()
```

## helloworld.kv

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation:'vertical'
    Button:
        text: "Hello world"
        id: btn1
        on_press: action()
    Button:
        text: "Hello world"
    Button:
        text: "Hello world"
    Button:
        text: "Love you world"
```

When I run it everything looks fine but when I press first button I get

**File "/home/user/Kivy/helloworld.kv", line 6, in 
     on_press: action()
 NameError: name 'action' is not defined**

I tried with `root.action()`  and `self.action()` but it didn't worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined `action` as a method of the App class, not the widget, so you can call it with `app.action()` in kv.

`app` is a kv keyword that resolves to the currently running application instance.